# _CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, sqflite

Want to ask again ... try implementing the data API stored in a local database ...
the form of the JSON API The object in which there is a JSON Array ... there was an error when wanting to load data from the API to Local database ... roughly this is an error because of "the wrong model or what

Api Service

```
class MealApiProvider {
  Future<List<Categories>> getAllMeal() async {
    var url = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php";
    Response response = await Dio().get(url);
    print("Hasil Respon ${response.data}");
    return (response.data as List).map((employee) {
      print('Inserting $employee');
      DBProvider.db.insertMeals(Categories.fromJson(employee));
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

Model

```
class DataMeal {
  final List<Categories> categories;

  DataMeal({this.categories});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'DataMeal{categories: $categories}';
  }

  factory DataMeal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataMeal(
      categories: List<Categories>.from(
        json["categories"].map(
          (categories) {
            return Categories.fromJson(categories);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "categories": List<dynamic>.from(
          categories.map(
            (x) => x.toJson(),
          ),
        ),
      };
}
```

Local DB

```
  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, '$nameDatabase');
    print('insert database $path');

    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $nameTable('
          'idCategory,'
          'strCategory TEXT,'
          'strCategoryThumb TEXT,'
          'strCategoryDescription TEXT'
          ')');
    });
  }

  insertMeals(DataMeal newMeal) async {
    await deleteAllMeal();
    final Database db = await database;
    final res = await db.insert("$nameTable", newMeal.toJson());
    print("inserting data $res");
    return res;
  }
```

Error

> return (response.data as List).map((employee)

[Respon Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Ubw.png)

Comment: Hey you're using wrong data type for array use List<dynamic> for array and use Map<String,dynamic> for JSON Object. Try it out it will work.

Comment: Which code did I change?

Comment: I cann't tell but may be able to after seeing your response.

Comment: please see the picture that I have updated
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Ubw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response contains map at the begining !
Try this

```
class MealApiProvider {
  Future<List<Categories>> getAllMeal() async {
    var url = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php";
    Response response = await Dio().get(url);
    print("Hasil Respon ${response.data}");
    //***Change below line****
    return (response.data['categories'] as List).map((employee) {
      print('Inserting $employee');
      DBProvider.db.insertMeals(Categories.fromJson(employee));
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

instead of

```
class MealApiProvider {
  Future<List<Categories>> getAllMeal() async {
    var url = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php";
    Response response = await Dio().get(url);
    print("Hasil Respon ${response.data}");
    //*** I change the below line !
    return (response.data as List).map((employee) {
      print('Inserting $employee');
      DBProvider.db.insertMeals(Categories.fromJson(employee));
    }).toList();
  }
}
```